# How to detect if a html element could be described by a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

for example:

```
<li class="list" id="first-list"></li>  

var li = document.getElementById("first-list");
matchSelector(li, "li.list"); // this should return true
```

now my solution could be described as:

```
function matchSelector(element, selector){  
     var all_matched_elements = $(selector);  
     return element in all_matched_elements
}
```

but obviously this includes some unnecessary work.
is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method.

Something like:

```
var li = document.getElementById("first-list");
matchSelector(li, "li.list");

function matchSelector(element, selector){  
  return $(element).is(selector);
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/NqwxQ/

Comment: great. do you know if I can extract this function from JQuery? because I can't use jquery but a framework which uses Sizzle to do the selector work in my company.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to determine if an element can be matched by the specified selector. This function returns a boolean value.

For instance:

```
var $li = $("li");
$li.each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(".list")) {
        // Take action
    }
});
```